# Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found

Tags: mongodb

While restart mongodb server using below command. its showing error like : Failed to restart mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
mongod --repair
sudo service mongodb start
```

Comment: Don't forget to specify `--dbpath` to `mongod` command, and ensure all the files are properly owned by the `mongod` user after repairing.
Also, before starting the service, be sure there is no pid file:  `/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
sudo systemctl unmask mongodb
```

and re-run

```
sudo service mongod start
```